# Wide context menu items; how do I turn this off?

Tags: windows-10, context-menu

When I right click on the taskbar the menu is as it is when I would touch the screen; very wide:

[image]

Tablet mode is not turned on and not even available:

[image]

I don't even have a touch screen (dual monitor setup with no touch capability).

Is there any way to restore this? I have obviously restarted countless times.

Comment: Yours appears to be the exact same size as mine (1920x1080, primary monitor in a dual screen desktop setup), and it looks like it usually does (to me), so I'm not sure what you're trying to 'turn off'?  Can you provide an example of what you expect it to look like?

Comment: What is your resolution set to?  If it's lower than your actual screen resolution, that can disable tablet mode.

Comment: @scriptHero I don't believe the OP's goal is to enable tablet mode. I believe he was showing it's disabled, expecting that what may be causing his context menus to appear wider than expected.  Perhaps they'll come back and clarify that for us. :)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 It's just a note from experience.  When I reduced my resolution from 2180x1440 to 1280x1024, it disabled tablet mode, made a mess of my desktop etc.  Just wondering if that could be the cause of the OP's problem as well.

Comment: this is a new feature of the 1511 update afaik, it can't be turned off